# How to know name of the person in the image?

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I implemented face recognition algorithm in raspberry pi(python 2.7 is was used), i have many sets of faces, if the captured face is one in database then the face is detected(i am using eigen faces algo). My question is can i know whose face(persons name) is detected? (can we have sort of tags to image and display name corresponding to it when the face is detected) Note: OpenCV used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *filename* of the image for that purpose. All you need to do is keep the filenames stored somewhere in your application, alongside the `Mat` objects.